# Strange behavior of datetime rounding between python 2 & 3

Tags: python, datetime, rounding

In python 2, we have:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1000000000005.0/1000.0)
datetime.datetime(2001, 9, 9, 1, 46, 40, 5000)
```

But in python 3, we have:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1000000000005.0/1000.0)
datetime.datetime(2001, 9, 9, 1, 46, 40, 4999)
```

What is the cause of this strange rounding behavior and is it intended? Isn't `1000000000005.0` still within the range of doubles with a few digits to spare?

Comment: Interesting find. Could you post your OS, python sys.version?

Comment: @dmg I've tested this on python 3.4.1, 3.4.2, linux & windows 7.

Comment: it  definitely has  got to do with how the rounding is done in  python3, if you use any value from 5 down it rounds down and up for values > 5

Comment: Comparing the sources, it seems that in Python 2 it rounds to the nearest microsecond, whereas in Python 3 it always rounds down.  This means any computing error that occurs internally, no matter how small, risks rounding the number down nearly a full microsecond, as occurs here.  I've no clue if this was done by design or is a bug.

Comment: you could use `datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=1000000000005.0/1000.0)` as a workaround (`utcfromtimestamp()` *might* (I don't know) produce different result if "right" timezone is used).

Comment: @ArminRigo: do you mean [`_PyTime_ROUND_DOWN` in `datetime_from_timestamp()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/981ba93bcbde/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#l4080)? Changing it to `_PyTime_ROUND_UP` produces `5000` here.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but seems to me they have lots of arguments for rounding. and v3.4 changed the behave. http://bugs.python.org/issue8860

Comment: It's not purely a 2 vs 3 difference.  There is no difference between python2.7.8 and python3.2.5, both return datetime.datetime(2001,9,9,1,46,40,5000). I'm using cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Below I have essentially included `utcfromtimestamp` (I modified it slightly to standalone).

In Python 2:

```
import time, datetime
def utcfromtimestamp(t):
    y, m, d, hh, mm, ss, weekday, jday, dst = time.gmtime(t)
    us = int((t % 1.0) * 1000000)
    ss = min(ss, 59)
    return datetime.datetime(y, m, d, hh, mm, ss, us)
```

In Python 3:

```
import time, datetime
def utcfromtimestamp(t):
    t, frac = divmod(t, 1.0)
    us = int(frac * 1e6)
    if us == 1000000:
        t += 1
        us = 0
    y, m, d, hh, mm, ss, weekday, jday, dst = time.gmtime(t)
    ss = min(ss, 59)
    return datetime.datetime(y, m, d, hh, mm, ss, us)
```

(The input `1000000000005.0/1000.0` is calculated to `1000000000.005`.)

In my standalone version:

Python 2 uses the modulus operator `%` to determine if the input is a whole number or a fraction.
The statement `(t % 1.0) * 1000000` then multiplies the fraction (in our case `0.004999995231628418`) by `1000000`. This returns `4999.995231628418`, which is rounded down to `4999` by `int`.

Python 3 uses `divmod` to return the whole number (`t`) `1000000000.0` and the fraction (`frac`) `0.005`.
Instead of returning this, it returns `t` as `1000000000` and `frac` as `0.004999995231628418`.
It then goes to calculating `us` using `frac * 1e6`. This is multiplying your `0.004999995231628418` by `1000000` resulting in `4999.995231628418`, which is rounded down to `4999` by `int`.

There is no real difference in the methods used. Both are accurate and return the same result. My conclusion is that Python 2 is rounding microseconds up,  while Python 3 is rounding them down.